# NativeScript Vue - Best way to navigate to other components while maintaining the same top section that has profile info?

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-vue

I want to have a top section for logged in users that has logged in status and profile avatar but I want everything below that different components.  How can I navigate to other components while a consistent topbar section?  Do I have to include the top bar code on every component?

Comment: You can customise the action bar

Comment: but that would still give the appearance of rerendering each time the page goes to a new component in the stack.  I want it to look like the top is a static piece and everything beneath it changes when the components change.

Comment: It depends how you manages your routes. In your root component you can have fixed top while in lower section you can move around your componts using routes

Comment: Thanks.  Is there any documentation on how to do this?  In my root, I just have: 
 `new Vue({render: h => h('frame', [h(router['app'])])}).$start()` and then all the logic is in the App.vue.

Comment: I don't know much about 'vue' but may be something like this https://github.com/nativescript-vue/nativescript-vue-router/blob/8dadf9744e5d8431bf3e9148e66b34f4849055b5/examples/nested-router/app.js#L49

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Frame](https://nativescript-vue.org/en/docs/elements/components/frame/) is the UI element that's responsible handling navigation. A Frame can display one Page at a time which can have a ActionBar.

If your intention is not to just duplicate the ActionBar code in every page, write Vue component that will only contain your ActionBar which can be imported in every other component.

You may use nested frames too, let the outer frame hold the ActionBar consistent over navigations on inner frame.

Comment: Thanks.  What is the best practice in this situation when building apps?  Out of the options you mention, would it be just having a dedicated Vue Component for a top ActionBar that I can import in each page or would it be using nested frames?  My concern is that even if I have the `navigateTo` field `animate` set to `false`, the ActionBar component will have to render again and "flash" briefly, which is I am trying to avoid.  However, I don't want to over complicate things.  If that is the best practice, I'll gladly do that but if nested frames is , I wouldn't mind investigating that approach.

Comment: There is no one stop solution for all requirements, each app / requirement is unique in some way. If you ask me, I would just go with Vue component and import it in every Page. But of course you might see a little flash as it's navigating (A new actionbar for the newly navigated page is rendered). If you want to avoid that, you must go with nested frames.

Comment: great, Thank you for your help